# Out of memory: Kill process mysqld on cent os 7

Tags: mysql

I am facing issue the kernal is again and agin killing mysql

And due to this tomcat stops arbitrarily.
My db size is approx 700 MB.

My application is fetching much more data on regular basis.

```
JVM memory usages
=================
 -Xms3000m
 -Xmx12000m
 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4000m 

my.cnf
======
[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
max_connections = 150
max_user_connections = 100
query_cache_size = 64M
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
net_buffer_length = 16K
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_file_per_table
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_type = on
#innodb_force_recovery = 1

performance-schema=0
# This setting allows the use of asynchronous I/O in InnoDB.
# The following files track usage of this resource:
# - /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
# - /proc/sys/fs/aio-nr
# Default limit is 65536, of which a single instance of mysql uses 2661 out of the box
innodb_use_native_aio = 1
default_storage_engine = MyISAM
open_files_limit=50000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

Ehcache enabled in my application.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: how much ram is on the machine? What MySQL version? Why are you defaulting to MyISAM? How many concurrent connections do you really support? Why are you running a memory hog like JVM on the same machine? What does `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` show as an SQL statement after being up a while before it crashes?

Comment: I don't see the cause of the problem having any relation to JSF nor Tomcat.

Comment: Hi @danblack, 

Mysql version is 5.6.39
Thread connected = 109

Comment: There was more than 2 questions. You can edit the question to provide all answers.

Comment: MySQL is not usually the cause of this problem.  It's often the victim of something else on the system making large demands for memory... https://serverfault.com/a/562476/153161